# How to implement a field in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with how to implement a field. My code contains `JButton`s and when I click on some of them it shows a new Pane with a question and answers and I want to implement a field in this pane, where I can write my answer( for example- A,B,C or D) but I don't know how exactly and which method to use. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Comment: Show what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show what you have done so far.As Uma said in comments you need to use textField. Here is sample code how it works. The code is for reference as your question is not very clear and does not have sample code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneWithInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField xField = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField yField = new JTextField(5);

      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("Input1:"));
      myPanel.add(xField);
      myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("input2:"));
      myPanel.add(yField);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
               "Please Enter input 1 and 2 Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("1 value: " + xField.getText());
         System.out.println("2 value: " + yField.getText());
      }
   }
}
```

code for input dialog from button on parent (myPanel)

```
  String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( myPanel,
          "Please Enter a value");
```